# I dont know why this error occurs, please help me

Tags: java, debugging

```
import java.util.Scanner;
  
 
  /**   
    * Calculates the amount of fuel needed.
    *
    * @param distance The distance of the trip.
    * @param milesPerLiter Total distance that could be achieved with 1 liter of fuel.
    * @return Total fuel needed.
    */
    public static double calcFuelNeeded(double distance, double milesPerLiter) {
               
               double fuelNeeded = distance / milesPerLiter;
               
              
               return (fuelNeeded);
                //FILL IN THE BODY
    }

   /**   
    * Calculates the total number of gallons needed.
    *
    * @param fuelNeeded Total fuel needed.
    * @param litersPerGallon The volume of each gallon.
    * @return Total number of gallons needed.
    */
    public static int calcGallonsFuelNeeded(double fuelNeeded, double litersPerGallon) {
                
               
                
                double gallonsFuel = Math.ceil(fuelNeeded / litersPerGallon);
                 
                return (int) gallonsFuel;//FILL IN THE BODY
    }

   /**   
    * Calculates the total cost needed.
    *
    * @param gallonsFuel Total number of gallons needed.
    * @param costPerGallon The cost of each gallon.
    * @return The total cost of the trip.
    */
    public static double calcCostNeeded(int gallonsFuel, double costPerGallon) {
               double costNeeded = gallonsFuel * costPerGallon;
           
               return costNeeded;//FILL IN THE BODY
    }
  
  
  
  
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the distance to be covered (miles):");
        double distance;
        
        
        distance = scnr.nextDouble();
        double milesPerLiter = 13.7;
        double litersPerGallon = 3.785;
        double costPerGallon = 2.629;
        
        scnr.close();
        
        System.out.println("Fuel Needed: " + calcFuelNeeded(distance, milesPerLiter) +  " liter(s)");
        System.out.println("Gallons needed: " + calcGallonsFuelNeeded( calcFuelNeeded(distance, milesPerLiter),  litersPerGallon) + " gallon(s)");
        System.out.println("Cost needed: " +calcCostNeeded( calcGallonsFuelNeeded( calcFuelNeeded(distance, milesPerLiter),  litersPerGallon),  costPerGallon) + " $" );
    }
```

Could someone please tell me what is wrong with this program, since there is always error appear like
[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the contents within a *class*

Example:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo {

    /**
     * Calculates the amount of fuel needed. * * @param distance The distance of the trip. * @param milesPerLiter Total distance that could be achieved with 1 liter of fuel. * @return Total fuel needed. */ public static double calcFuelNeeded(double distance, double milesPerLiter) {

        double fuelNeeded = distance / milesPerLiter;


        return (fuelNeeded);
        //FILL IN THE BODY
    }
    /**
     * Calculates the total number of gallons needed. * * @param fuelNeeded Total fuel needed. * @param litersPerGallon The volume of each gallon. * @return Total number of gallons needed. */ public static int calcGallonsFuelNeeded(double fuelNeeded, double litersPerGallon) {

        double gallonsFuel = Math.ceil(fuelNeeded / litersPerGallon);

        return (int) gallonsFuel;//FILL IN THE BODY
    }
    /**
     * Calculates the total cost needed. * * @param gallonsFuel Total number of gallons needed. * @param costPerGallon The cost of each gallon. * @return The total cost of the trip. */ public static double calcCostNeeded(int gallonsFuel, double costPerGallon) { double costNeeded = gallonsFuel * costPerGallon;

        return costNeeded;//FILL IN THE BODY
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the distance to be covered (miles):");
        double distance;


        distance = scnr.nextDouble();
        double milesPerLiter = 13.7;
        double litersPerGallon = 3.785;
        double costPerGallon = 2.629;

        scnr.close();

        System.out.println("Fuel Needed: " + calcFuelNeeded(distance, milesPerLiter) +  " liter(s)");
        System.out.println("Gallons needed: " + calcGallonsFuelNeeded( calcFuelNeeded(distance, milesPerLiter),  litersPerGallon) + " gallon(s)");
        System.out.println("Cost needed: " +calcCostNeeded( calcGallonsFuelNeeded( calcFuelNeeded(distance, milesPerLiter),  litersPerGallon),  costPerGallon) + " $" );
    }
}
```